# MEAN SATCK angular2:get data from multiple api in typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

1. Working with angular2,nodejs,expressjs,mongodb.
2. i want all api to return data and show over html page.
3. here is my code for .ts file.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe4q6.png)

   - all apis tested working fine returns data form mongodb.
   - but very first api return data and shows over the html page.
   - in this case countphones api retuns data and other two not .
   - but when first is commented second starts showing data over the html
     page.
   - the case is like first come only shows.

Comment: `return` means that's the last thing the code will run. It will ignore what comes after the `return` block.

Comment: then how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class AppComponent  {

phone$ = http.get("...").map(r => r.json())
laptop$ = http.get("...").map(r => r.json())
television$ = http.get("...").map(r => r.json())

ngOnInit(){
    Observable
    .forkJoin(this.phone$, this.laptop$, this.television$)
    .subscribe(([phones, laptops, televisions])=>{
        this.phones = phones;
        this.laptios = laptops;
        this.televisions = televisions;
  });
}
}
```